# How can you change a value in javascript from another webpage?

Tags: javascript

I've created a loop in JS and have a condition that say if(minute === 15), once the clock hits 15mins past (whatever) the condition is met.

I want to make that "15" a variable that can be changed from another webpage.

website.com/alarm
Contains the loop

website.com/alarmConfig
Contains a text field used to set the minute.

I originally was going to make that script read a notepad that has the value in it, but because the page will be running on a range of devices I need those browsers to be able to do that.

What would be the simpliest way of doing this? Doesn't need to be in real-time

Comment: You generally can't do this.

Comment: You can, using AJAX, to read data from another website. I don't know if this is what you are after.

Comment: Same device? Or different ones?

Comment: The closest thing that I can think of that sounds remotely similar to your problem is using [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker).  It allows for communication between pages in a browser context (tabs, windows, iframes, etc).  However it does not have support across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. But you can use cookies or localStorage to share these variables.

> For simple synchronous storage access HTML 5 introduces the localStorage attribute on the Window object:
>
> localStorage["status"] = "Idling.";

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Ajax call to "website.com/alarmConfig" webpage and then retrieve the value of the text field used to set the minute and then update the loop in "website.com/alarm".
Also, you will make the call after the said duration is over and once you retrieve the updated value, you can run the loop again.

Comment: If you could give more details of what you are after, then that could be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.